# Is $L=\sin^2(t) \frac{d}{dt}$ a linear differential operator?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential operator

$$L=\sin^2(t) \frac{d}{dt}$$

If it acts on the sum of two functions, $y_1(t)$ and $y_2(t)$, you get

$$\begin{align*}
L(y_1(t)+y_2(t))&=\sin^2(t) \frac{d}{dt}(y_1(t)+y_2(t))\\
&=sin^2(t) \frac{d}{dt}y_1(t) + sin^2(t) \frac{d}{dt}y_2(t)\\
&=L(y_1(t)) + L(y_2(t))
\end{align*}$$

If it acts on a constant multiple of a function $y(t)$, say $\lambda y(t)$, you get

$$\begin{align*}
L(\lambda y(t)) &=sin^2(t) \frac{d}{dt}(\lambda y(t)) \\
&= \lambda sin^2(t) \frac{d}{dt}(y(t)) \\
&= \lambda L(y(t))
\end{align*}$$

So this differential operator must be linear. **However, my brain is telling me that it shouldn't be. Have I gone wrong?**

If this is in fact a differential operator, wouldn't any function of $t$ work as a differential operator?

Comment: you  are right. $L$ is a singular linear operator but not constant coefficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that it is a linear operator. I think the cognitive dissonance you're experiencing is that you're thrown off by the $\sin^2 t$ part. This is clearly not linear in $t$. However differential operators do not act on the variable more than the functions of that variable. The linearity is with respect to functions of $t$, not $t$.

To compare, the operator $\mathcal{O}f = \left(\frac{df}{dt}\right)^2$ is not linear since $\mathcal{O}(f+g) = \left(\frac{df}{dt}+\frac{dg}{dt}\right)^2$. This is not equal to $\mathcal{O}f+\mathcal{O}g = \left(\frac{df}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dg}{dt}\right)^2$ in general.

Answer (score 1):

It is a linear operator alright. In general, if $D = \frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}$, we can consider polynomials in $D$, which coefficients are functions of $t$: $$P = a_n(t) D^n + \cdots + a_1(t)D + a_0\,{\rm id},$$ where $D^k = \frac{{\rm d}^k}{{\rm d}t^k}$, meaning that $D^kf = \frac{{\rm d}^kf}{{\rm d}t^k}$, and *not* $\left(\frac{{\rm d}f}{{\rm d}t}\right)^k$. Your example above is a particular case of this. A nice fact about these operators, is that $P$ and $Q$ are operators as above *with all the coefficients being constants*, then $P\circ Q = Q\circ P$, that is, you can do computations and factoring just like ordinary polynomials. For more details on this, I refer refer you to chapter $2$ (and beyond) of [An Introduction to Linear Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/020103946X).